# WPF Style Triggers: Using a Context Menu on Variable Width Grid

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

My application has a sidebar. This sidebar is usually collapsed (width 20 pixels), but when I mouse hover over the sidebar, it expands (600 pixels). This is set in WPF with the "IsMouseOver" property on a grid

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5 30" Name="GridCollapsible">
 <Grid.Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
   <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="Width" Value="600"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
     <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
    </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
 </Grid.Style> 
 ...
```

One of the elements that is a child of this grid is a ListView. This ListView has a ContextMenu

```
<ListView Name="TodayCalendarListBox" Margin="0 10 0 0" FontSize="16" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
 <ListView.ContextMenu>
  <ContextMenu>
   <MenuItem Header="Completed" Click="CompletedMenuItem_Click"/>
   <MenuItem Header="Missed" Click="MissedMenuItem_Click"/>
  </ContextMenu>
 </ListView.ContextMenu>
...
```

**When I right click the list view item and open the context menu, the context menu opens in the background.**

I have currently tried subscribing to the ContextMenuOpening and ContextMenuClosing events in the DockPanel that is the Parent container to the ListView

```
<DockPanel Margin="8" ContextMenuOpening="ContextMenu_ContextMenuOpening" ContextMenuClosing="ContextMenu_ContextMenuClosing">
```

```
        private void ContextMenu_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
        {
            GridCollapsible.Width = 600;
        }

        private void ContextMenu_ContextMenuClosing(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
        {
            GridCollapsible.Width = 20;
        }
```

These events fire as expected, and manually fixing the width in code behind to 600 makes the context menu appear on top of my collapsible grid, as expected. **However, I can then not reactivate the MouseOver trigger** - my collapsible grid is permanently stuck at a width of 20, regardless of mouse over.

How can I reset the grid width so that it operates as a mouse over trigger? What code can I add to the Context Menu closing event to reset the collapsibleGrid to its default?

Is there a neater and more elegant solution to this?

Picture of the situation (no mouse over --> mouse over and context menu) for clarity.

[image]

Comment: Instead of setting the property to a local value, try to call `GridCollapsible.SetValue(Grid.WidthProperty, 600.0)` in `ContextMenu_ContextMenuOpening` and `GridCollapsible.ClearValue(Grid.WidthProperty)` in `ContextMenu_ContextMenuClosing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the property to a local value, call `GridCollapsible.SetValue(Grid.WidthProperty, 600.0)` in `ContextMenu_ContextMenuOpening` and then clear the value by calling `GridCollapsible.ClearValue(Grid.WidthProperty)` in `ContextMenu_ContextMenuClosing`.